# Spring data mongo - Get sum of array of object in mongo

Tags: mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I have an issue getting the sum of an array of objects, Document is mentioned below.

```
{
   "orderNumber":123,
   "items":[
      {
         "price":2
      },
      {
         "price":10
      }
   ]
}
```

I need the below document

```
{
   "orderNumber":123,
   "totalItemsValue":12,
   "items":[
      {
         "price":2
      },
      {
         "price":10
      }
   ]
}
```

Sum of prices in **totalItemsValue** field.I need a solution in spring mongo data.I will be thankful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There ae lot of ways, easiest way is given below. Spring data doesn't provide any operation for `$addFields`. So we do a [Trick](http://pingax.com/trick-convert-mongo-shell-query-equivalent-java-objects/).

Autowire the  mongoTemplate

```
@Autowired
private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;
```

And the method is like

```
public List<Object> test() {
    Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(
        a-> new Document("$addFields",
                new Document("totalItemsValue",
                    new Document("$reduce"
                        new Document()
                        .append("input","$items")
                        .append("initialValue",0)
                        .append("in",
                            new Document("$add",Arrays.asList("$$value",1))
                        )
                    )                   
            )
        )

    ).withOptions(AggregationOptions.builder().allowDiskUse(Boolean.TRUE).build());

    return mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, mongoTemplate.getCollectionName(YOUR_COLLECTION.class), Object.class).getMappedResults();

}
```

**Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/X2-Bfigt56z)**